# Why does Mybatis Interceptor get duplicate parameters

Tags: mybatis

I want to get some params before sql execute, but when I get params by Interceptor I found it to be repetitive,parameter types have basic types and maps And when I modified the data in one map, the data in the other map also changed

[Gets a list of parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8GzZ.png)

[Modified the data in one map, the data in the other map also changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkkOa.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html).

> You can pass multiple parameters to a mapper method. If you do, they will be named by the literal "param" followed by their position in the parameter list by default, for example: #{param1}, #{param2} etc. If you wish to change the name of the parameters (multiple only), then you can use the @Param("paramName") annotation on the parameter.

Although the doc does not mention, the default/implicit names (i.e "param1", "param2", ...) are still available even when you use `@Param` to name the parameters explicitly.

So, for example, the following two declarations are practically the same.

```java
@Select("select * from users where id = #{id} and name = #{name}")
User select(@Param("id")Integer id, @Param("name")String name);
```

```java
@Select("select * from users where id = #{param1} and name = #{param2}")
User select(@Param("id")Integer id, @Param("name")String name);
```

ℹ️I do not recommend using the default/implicit names if you used `@Param` because it is an undocumented behavior and could break in the future.

Comment: You missunderstand me, The Oracle server character set is US7ASCII, but the parameters obtained are GBK, so I need to convert the parameters to the character set before SQL execution. For generality, I want to customize the interceptor of mybatis to implement.

Comment: You didn't post any code, but there may be `@Param("params")` on your mapper method, right? The other parameter name "param1" is an alias (another name) of the same parameter automatically assigned by MyBatis. They reference the same object (the map in your case), so if you edit "params", the change will be applied to "param1" and vice versa. By the way, storing GBK data into US7ASCII database sounds crazy....you should consider changing the database character set.

Comment: You're right,I didn't notice it before, @Param("params") does exist in my mapper method.This is not a new project cannot change the dataset,So I can only transform the character set.